# Alt-tab short cut not working after 19.04 Update

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, ubuntu-19.04

I did an update from 18.04->18.10->19.04 Ubuntu. After the update the switch applications or switch windows functionality is not working. Tried alt-tab and super-tab.

I tried to reset the keyboard shortcut in settings and tried again after setting it. still the same. All the other shortcuts with alt works. For ex: alt-f4 close the window. But when I replaced alt-f4 with alt-tab it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem.

It seems that in Ubuntu 19.04 (or maybe from 18.10) the "switch applications" changed shortcut key combination.

Now it is "<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>".

[image: Switch application on Ubuntu 19.04 wayland]

If you want to change to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> just go to:

**Settings** > **Devices** > **Keyboard** and under **Keyboard Shortcuts** change **Switch applications** shortcut